# Problem with creating Compound Control in Android

Tags: android, custom-controls

I am learning to create a compound control in android.
For starters i tried an edit text with an attached button to clear it.

The problem is even though i can see the compound control in the graphical view of the
main.xml, there is an error message :  "Custom view ClearableEditText is not using the 2- or 3-argument View constructors; XML attributes will not work"
This is not visible in project explorer under errors only in the xml graphical view
i am able to compile and run but get a force close.

XML : COMPOUND CONTROL clearable_edit_text.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
    <EditText android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
    <Button android:id="@+id/clearButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CLEAR"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

CLASS

```
public class ClearableEditText extends LinearLayout 
{
    EditText et;
    Button btn;

    public ClearableEditText(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        LayoutInflater li=(LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        li.inflate(R.layout.clearable_edit_text,this,true);

        et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.clearButton);

        hookupButton();
    }

    private void hookupButton()
    {
        btn.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                et.setText("");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
    <com.commsware.android.merge.ClearableEditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
    <com.commsware.android.merge.ClearableEditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class extends `LinearLayout` but you never add any views to it. You need to call `addView(...)` and pass your inflated view as the parameter.

Also, to define your view in XML you need to override the 2 and 3 argument constructors for a `LinearLayout`. Add this to your code:

```
public ClearableEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

    super( context, attrs );
}

public ClearableEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {

    super( context, attrs, defStyle );
}
```

To get all 3 constructors to use the same initialization code, move your code from the single argument constructor to the 3 argument constructor, then in the other 2 constructors call `this(context, null, 0)` and `this(context, attrs, 0)` respectively.

Comment: It seems a 3 argument constructor does not exist for LinearLayout, it said the constructor was not defined.So i just used 1 and 2 arg constructors and the app worked.

Comment: I tried to use <merge> tag in main as suggested in the diff topic that i researched for the qst to remove the LinearLayout. When i did this the only one instance of the compound component shows the rest are not visible.